# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Could you help me? I got this error in a populated drop-down list.

```
<select ng-init="type = 'Fixo'" ng-model="type" class="form-control input-lg">
     <option ng-repeat="p in ['Fixo','Celular']" ng-value="p" ng-bind="p"></option>
 </select>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your code works... but you can take advantage of `ng-options` instead of do it manually with `ng-repeat`. Chek this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/0AyBokCC6C84X9wK0zb9?p=preview)...

Comment: The exacly error message is: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[ng-repeat='p in ['Fixo','Celular']']

Comment: Please provide more code...

Comment: @The.Bear I changed it to ng-options and working good. Thx a lot. Thank you too Tim Harker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same strange error. It was happening with string arrays, but worked fine for number arrays, so here is my jenky fix:

```
<select ng-init="type = 'Fixo'" ng-model="type" class="form-control input-lg">
<option ng-repeat="p in [0,1]" ng-init="x=['Fixo','Celular'][p]" ng-value="x" ng-bind="x">
</option> 
</select>
```

but as others have mentioned, for select you can use ng-options. If this occurs for anyone as it did with me in another use case, you might try my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't produce the error...

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-init="type = 'Fixo'" ng-model="type" class="form-control input-lg">
     <option ng-repeat="p in ['Fixo','Celular']" ng-value="p" ng-bind="p"></option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same issue. Took me a while to figure it out, but the "bug" is in the quotes. Angular does not recognize '] . All you have to do is switch your quotes, like so:

```
 <option ng-repeat='p in ["Fixo","Celular"]' ng-value="p" ng-bind="p"></option>
```

Now you won't have any '], whereas "] is ok. Problem solved with no weird workarounds.